# Balanced String Counter

Tags: java, combinatorics

I'm applying for a java internship and one of the tasks to complete goes like this -

> Balanced words counter - Balanced words definition: The word is balanced if every letter that occurs in it occurs in the same number of time. E.g. the words: “mama”, “ear”, “aabbcbcccbaa” are balanced but the words “dad”, “elephant”, “abcba” are not. Additionally, the balanced word is not empty.
>
> Create a “BalancedWordsCounter” class with one public method called “count” (you can create other private methods) which has to count how many balanced subwords exist in the input word.
>
> - method should receive String (parameter name = “input”)
> - method should return Integer
> - the input should contain the letters only, throw an exception if the text contains other characters.
> - if the input is null then method should throw an exception
>
> Create a “BalancedWordsCounterTest” and create a test methods for below cases:
>
> - input = “aabbabcccba” result = 28
> - input = “” result = 0
> - input = “abababa1” result = RuntimeException
> - input = null result = RuntimeException

I'm tied at the test case with result 28 - what needs to be done so the number 28 is produced? I tried visualizing the problem before coding the answer, but the only reasonable idea I got was something like this -

```
1 a     
2 ab            
3 abc       
4 2a        
5 3a            
5 4a        
6 2a2b  
7 3a3b      
8 4a4b      
9 ac        
10 2a2c 
11 3a3c         
12 4a4c     
13 2b       
14 2b2c     
15 3b3c     
16 4b4c     
17 b    
18 c        
19 3a   
20 3b   
21 3c   
22 bc   
23 4b   
24 4c       
25 2c       
26 2a2b2c   
27 3a3b3c   
28 4a4b4c
```

but the case here is that i would have to use 4xC, which isn't the case.
What am I missing?
I'm not really asking about ready solutions, but for some insights on what the problem actually is.

@Edit -
for questions about the code I already made - I didnt produce any code for this because I don't really understand the question therefore I was counting on some insight into what the problem is about, because apparently I wasn't able to come up with other solution that what I specified, but the case is that's not really 1:1 with the question(it assumes the string has 4 a 4 b and 4c, which isn't the case) ;/

Comment: You seem to be missing some `java` code from your question. What have you tried, and where are you stuck? Refer [help] on asking good questions

Comment: Please give some sample code so we can better help answer your question. What did you try, and why did it fail?

Comment: I believe it is the count of individual strings you can form with the given string without changing the order of the characters. This is the list of substrings I came up with: a,a,b,b,a,b,c,c,c,b,a,aa,bb,ab,aabb,abba,ba,aabbab,abc,bc,cc,ccc,cba,aabbabccc,cc,cb,ba
which is 28. This would also explain why "" returns 0 as no substrings can be created

Comment: @Portal im counting again and again and it's 27 examples and I can't seem to find the 28th, altho this would be the logical solution I didnt think of...

Comment: @Bajter I think Portal was missing a second 'ab'. Basically, all single characters and all 2-char words are always balanced. Therefore you start with 11 + 10. Then you will find 7 more with more than 2 character lenght.

Comment: @Slomo yes! Thank You so much, this has been bugging me literally for almost 1.5week

Comment: @Slomo correct, I seem to have lost one in the copy paste

Answer (score 1):

The question to answer is: how is "subword" defined. Comments to the question suggest that "subword" can be seen as any word you can "cut" from the original input.

For the input in question, "aabbabcccba" you can cut these balanced subwords (the word itself is *not* balanced by the definition given, as it contains 4 * `a`, 4 * `b` but only 3 * `c`)

```
aabbabcccba
a
 a
  b
   b
    a
     b
      c
       c
        c
         b
          a
aa
 ab
  bb
   ba
    ab
     bc
      cc
       cc
        cb
         ba
    abc
      ccc
        cba
aabb
 abba
aabbab
aabbabccc
```

In the above list, the original word is on top, and each word below is written at the position where you find it in the original input.
When you count the total lines in the text, you get 29, but the first is the original word, which is *not* balanced as described above, so the result is 28, as expected.

Comment: I wrote this answer because I saw that exercises with balanced words seem to be quite common, also questions related to them in Stack Overflow - so it should help new visitiors searching for this. Thanks to all the commenters on the question, they helped find the solution.

Comment: yeah, the thing is I couldnt find anything online for the exact problem I had, all balanced subwords/substring problems where about symmetry, or the amount of true words, or some other similar letter counting and I couldnt deduce anything from them, I hope your answer will help the google algorithm find it when some other noobie like me will need something similar!

Comment: To be honest, I believe most of these questions are foggy by design. They most likely want the students to reverse engineer by using the example outputs.